# How can I get object from its unique id in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

```
canvas=Canvas(...)
unique_id=canvas.create_rectangle(...)
unique_id.tag_bind(...)
```

I get this error because it is an integer

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tag_bind'
```

I need to get the object

Comment: Canvas items aren't actually objects; the integer ID is all you get.  You do things with them by calling methods on the Canvas itself, passing these IDs as parameters.

Comment: thanks. How should I call tag_bind for this specific rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use tag_bind in the following with with canvas items.

```
canvas=Canvas(...)
unique_id=canvas.create_rectangle(...)
canvas.tag_bind(unique_id,...)
```